# how to do it in Rstudio?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have Multiple data files with same column names in each file with 5 features each, I want to collect it under one data frame and i want to call each file individually as when it required..
EX:-

```
A<-subset(data_new1, GROSS_SALES>0 & GROSS_SALES)

B<-subset(data_new1, GROSS_SALES>2 & GROSS_SALES<4)

C<-subset(data_new1, GROSS_SALES>4 & GROSS_SALES<6)
```

collect it under one data frame

```
x = (A,B,C)
```

and want to call it when required...
suppose, i want B from data frame

Comment: Please look at the "how to ask a good question" guidelines and this guide specific to asking good questions for R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can try with rbind. It binds rows together.

```
x <- rbind(A,B,C)
```

However the solution doesn't have nothing to do with Rstudio: it's basic R.
Rstudio is an IDE